# Object animator is not working

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to animate color of view using object animator but it's not changing color. her is code sample

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

    colorAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(button.getBackground().mutate(),"tint",
            getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        colorAnimator.start();

}else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){

        colorAnimator=ObjectAnimator.ofObject(button.getBackground().mutate(),"tint",new ArgbEvaluator(),
            getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    colorAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        colorAnimator.start();
}
```

I have not added object animator object to button?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method for animating a View's background color -

```
public static void animateImageViewBackground(final View viewToAnimate, int colorFrom, int colorTo, int animationDuration)
{

    ValueAnimator colorAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofObject(new ArgbEvaluator(), colorFrom, colorTo);

    colorAnimation.setDuration(animationDuration);

    colorAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {
            int newColor = (int) animator.getAnimatedValue();
            viewToAnimate.setBackgroundColor(newColor);
        }
    });
    colorAnimation.start();
}
```